# Is this SET TIME ZONE supposed to work like this with sqlx?

Tags: postgresql, rust, timezone, timestamp-with-timezone, rust-sqlx

[As explained here](https://docs.rs/sqlx/latest/sqlx/pool/struct.PoolOptions.html#example-additional-parameters) I'm using the below code:

```rust
use sqlx::Executor;
use sqlx::postgres::PgPoolOptions;

let pool = PgPoolOptions::new()
  .after_connect(|conn, _meta| Box::pin(async move {
    conn.execute("SET TIME ZONE 'Europe/Berlin';").await?;

    let result: (time::OffsetDateTime,) = sqlx::query_as("SELECT current_timestamp").fetch_one(conn).await?;

    println!("Current Time in Europe/Berlin: {}", result.0);

    Ok(())
  }))
  .connect("postgres:// …").await?;
```

and the result is:

```
Current Time in Europe/Berlin: 2024-02-06 22:39:37.194022 +00:00:00
```

which is wrong because the current Berlin time is "23" not "22" (which is UTC).

My database is currently on UTC by default (from postgresql.conf file).

And it works if I use the below code in a Postgresql query:

```sql
SET TIME ZONE 'Europe/Berlin';
SELECT current_timestamp;
```

Where am I wrong?

#### Info

- SQLx version: `0.7.3`
- SQLx features enabled: `"macros", "postgres", "runtime-tokio", "time"`
- Database server and version: `Postgres v16.1`
- Operating system: `Windows 10`
- `rustc --version`: `rustc 1.75.0 (82e1608df 2023-12-21)`

Comment: I'm going to say it is `OffsetDateTime` setting the timestamp back to `UTC`.

Comment: Why do you even want to set timezone from outside of the database in the first place? Shouldn't this be configured in the database itself?

Answer (score 1):

Current UTC time in Berlin is the same as current UTC time in Tōkyō. The timestamp is correct and the text you added to it isn't incorrect - it's just that the whole thing is pretty confusing, because the location has nothing to do with what time it currently is if you're operating on timezone-aware timestamps, which denote *absolute* point in time.

It goes without saying that doing `set time zone` in a query has no impact on your Rust app time zone offset configuration - [`time`](https://docs.rs/time/latest/time/index.html) uses system's offset. If your aim was for your Rust app to print out the `2024-02-06 23:39:37.194022 +01:00:00`, you would have to change your system's or app's time zone. The value of `timestamp` **`with`** `time zone` you save to `OffsetDateTime` remains unaffected by that, it's just output format that changes - again, those timestamps are absolute.

If you're looking for an "observed time", there's [`at time zone`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-ZONECONVERT) returning just that, which means stripping the timezone info to give you ["a picture of a clock"](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_timestamp_.28without_time_zone.29) taken at a location in a given timezone. [db<>fiddle:](https://dbfiddle.uk/1jtARZD8)

```
select now();
```

| now |
| --- |
| 2024-02-07 07:23:15.314852+00 |

```
set time zone 'Europe/Berlin';
select now();
```

| now |
| --- |
| 2024-02-07 08:23:15.316844+01 |

```
set time zone 'Europe/Berlin';
select now() at time zone 'UTC'
```

| timezone |
| --- |
| 2024-02-07 07:23:15.317335 |

```sql
set timezone='utc';
create table test(ts timestamp, tstz timestamptz);
insert into test values
('2024-02-07 12:00+01', '2024-02-07 12:00+01'),
('2024-02-07 12:00+02', '2024-02-07 12:00+02'),
('2024-02-07 12:00+03', '2024-02-07 12:00+03'),
('2024-02-07 12:00+04', '2024-02-07 12:00+04')
returning *,ts   at time zone 'UTC' "ts at tz",
            tstz at time zone 'UTC' "tstz at tz";
```

| ts | tstz | ts at tz | tstz at tz |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2024-02-07 12:00:00 | 2024-02-07 11:00:00+00 | 2024-02-07 12:00:00+00 | 2024-02-07 11:00:00 |
| 2024-02-07 12:00:00 | 2024-02-07 10:00:00+00 | 2024-02-07 12:00:00+00 | 2024-02-07 10:00:00 |
| 2024-02-07 12:00:00 | 2024-02-07 09:00:00+00 | 2024-02-07 12:00:00+00 | 2024-02-07 09:00:00 |
| 2024-02-07 12:00:00 | 2024-02-07 08:00:00+00 | 2024-02-07 12:00:00+00 | 2024-02-07 08:00:00 |

```sql
set timezone='Australia/Sydney';
select *,ts   at time zone 'Australia/Sydney' "ts at tz",
         tstz at time zone 'Australia/Sydney' "tstz at tz"
from test;
```

| ts | tstz | ts at tz | tstz at tz |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2024-02-07 12:00:00 | 2024-02-07 22:00:00+11 | 2024-02-07 12:00:00+11 | 2024-02-07 22:00:00 |
| 2024-02-07 12:00:00 | 2024-02-07 21:00:00+11 | 2024-02-07 12:00:00+11 | 2024-02-07 21:00:00 |
| 2024-02-07 12:00:00 | 2024-02-07 20:00:00+11 | 2024-02-07 12:00:00+11 | 2024-02-07 20:00:00 |
| 2024-02-07 12:00:00 | 2024-02-07 19:00:00+11 | 2024-02-07 12:00:00+11 | 2024-02-07 19:00:00 |