# How to make Postgres return timestamps in a given timezone?

Tags: postgresql, rust, timezone, timestamp-with-timezone, rust-sqlx

I'm using `sqlx` 0.7.3 and `time` 0.3.34.

I have this struct:

```rust
#[derive(Debug, sqlx::FromRow)]
pub struct Game {
    pub id: String,
    pub created_at: time::OffsetDateTime,
    pub date_time: time::OffsetDateTime,
    pub score: i64,
    // and many other fields
}
```

I can read with queries like:

```rust
let query = "SELECT * from games"

let games = query.build_query_as::<Game>().fetch_all(db_connection).await?;
```

and I can insert with queries like:

```rust
let query = r#"INSERT INTO "games" ("id", ..columns...) VALUES ($1, $2, ...and other values...) RETURNING *"#;

let games = sqlx::query_as::<_, Game>(query)
    .bind(value)
    .bind(another_value)
    .fetch_one(db_connection)
    .await?;
```

and everything works (other more difficult queries too).

Now the issue.

The `created_at` and `date_time` fields are saved in the database as PostgreSQL's `timestamptz` type. Great.

But when I retrieve those fields I need to get them in the current user's timezone.

Example:

If the current user querying that games data is currently on timezone `Europe/Berlin` the backend code in Rust should work on that struct datetime fields on that timezone, not on `UTC` which apparently is the default using `time::OffsetDateTime` with sqlx.

I know I can do conversion on backend in Rust code (for example converting the `time::OffsetDateTime` to `time::PrimitiveDateTime` or using [time-tz crate](https://crates.io/crates/time-tz)'s methods), but **I would like to do conversion directly in PostgreSQL**.

I read I can use the `AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Berlin'` PG's construct to do this, but what about all dates in all the query? Even when I use something like `RETURNING *` at the end of a PG's CTE?

I read I can use instead `SET TIME ZONE 'Europe/Berlin'` before the queries and [I tried it](https://github.com/launchbadge/sqlx/issues/3038) but sqlx's author answered:

> `query_as` uses the binary protocol which always outputs timestamps in UTC.

So I'm lost now.

Is it possible to let PostgreSQL return timestamps in the timezone I need, query by query?

Comment: Yes, by using `SET TIME ZONE 'Europe/Berlin'`.  The issue is with `query_as`, what if you use [query](https://docs.rs/sqlx/latest/sqlx/macro.query.html)?

Comment: How do you inspect the value after pulling it from Postgres to Rust and what are the time-related locale settings there?

Answer (score 1):

you could use [chrono](https://docs.rs/chrono/latest/chrono/)

> **DateTime** is timezone-aware and must be constructed from the TimeZone object, which defines how the local date is converted to and
> back from the UTC date. There are three well-known TimeZone
> implementations:
>
> - Utc specifies the UTC time zone. It is most efficient.

```
use chrono::{DateTime, Utc};

pub struct Game {
    pub id: String,
    pub created_at: DateTime<Utc>,
    pub date_time: DateTime<Utc>,
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Technically, you can set up a `view` or a `rule` to force PostgreSQL to quietly cast your `timestamptz` to `timestamp` using `at time zone` that'd use the current TimeZone setting configured by `SET TIME ZONE 'Europe/Berlin'` issued by the client. [Demo at db<>fiddle:](https://dbfiddle.uk/ywB22MNO)

```
create table test(tstz timestamptz);
insert into test values ('today') returning tstz;
```

| tstz |
| --- |
| 2024-02-10 00:00:00+00 |

```
create view v_test as 
  select tstz at time zone current_setting('timezone',true) as tstz 
  from test;

select tstz from v_test;
```

| tstz |
| --- |
| 2024-02-10 00:00:00 |

```
SET TIME ZONE 'Europe/Berlin';
select tstz from v_test;
```

| tstz |
| --- |
| 2024-02-10 01:00:00 |

> Is it possible to let Postgresql return the dates in the timezone I need, query by query?

The `view` above does just that, but I think you should reconsider if that's what you want.

`OffsetDateTime`/`timestamptz` are absolute - I think we established that [last time you asked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77951275/5298879).

The reason `SET TIME ZONE 'Europe/Berlin'` doesn't affect what's happening in Rust after you pull it down from PostgreSQL is because it affects how PostgreSQL interprets timezone-**un**aware timestamps *on input* to `timestamptz` and how it prints [`timestamptz`, `timetz`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME) and their [corresponding range types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-BUILTIN) *out* to you. The underlying value is absolute, and however, wherever Rust reads it into `OffsetDateTime`, it remains absolute.

By design, no matter what time zone or location you obtain or inspect them in, makes absolutely no difference to the value. Your locale might affect default display format, still without affecting the value. If you want to dumb the value down to a relative timestamp, you do need to use `time::PrimitiveDateTime` in Rust or shift&strip in PostgreSQL using `at time zone` in the queries issued by the clients or in the view you'll force them to target instead of the actual table holding the actual `timestamptz`.

---

This:

> `query_as` uses the binary protocol which always outputs timestamps in UTC.

contributes little to your problem. It might be an implementation detail how transfer is simplified - it's easier to force both ends to communicate in UTC and skip offset than to also transfer offset and shift accordingly. Unless you dumb down the value and switch to relative timestamps, the stored and transferred "form" of the timestamp**tz** should not matter to you.

If you made it this far, you might be interested in [`.to_offset()`](https://docs.rs/time/latest/time/struct.OffsetDateTime.html#method.to_offset).

Answer (score 1):

After `SET TIME ZONE 'Europe/Berlin'`, all you need is a plain cast to `timestamp`:

```
SELECT id, created_at::timestamp, date_time::timestamp, score FROM games;
```

This cast uses the setting of the current session implicitly (which is why it's only "stable", not "immutable").

Works in a `RETURNING` clause as well:

```
INSERT INTO games (id, ...) VALUES ($1, ...)
RETURNING id, created_at::timestamp, date_time::timestamp, score;
```

Alternatively, omit the `SET TIME ZONE` command and coerce with the `AT TIME ZONE` construct explicitly. Then you can use a custom time zone for every expression. Again, the result is type `timestamp` for `timestamptz` input.

Basics:

- [Ignoring time zones altogether in Rails and PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571392/ignoring-time-zones-altogether-in-rails-and-postgresql/9576170#9576170)

Most clients use the "text" protocol (which is usually more portable). The text representation of a `timestamptz` value reflects the current time zone setting:

```sql
est=> SET TIME ZONE 'UTC';
SET
test=> SELECT now() AS tstz, now()::timestamp AS ts;
              tstz             |            ts
-------------------------------+----------------------------
 2024-02-10 23:26:26.810186+00 | 2024-02-10 23:26:26.810186
(1 row)

test=> SET TIME ZONE 'EUROPE/BERLIN';
SET
test=> SELECT now() AS tstz, now()::timestamp AS ts;
              tstz             |            ts
-------------------------------+----------------------------
 2024-02-11 00:26:35.266357+01 | 2024-02-11 00:26:35.266357
(1 row)
```

The same `timestamptz` value has many different (but equivalent) text representations. So the problem only arises with the "binary" protocol, that does not superimpose the time zone information.